# Android listview that loads dynamic data on scroll up and down and clears existing data

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I am developing an android application, that shows more than 10,000 records per search in a listview. I can not hold more than 20 records at a time to ensure application does not run into crash. On up an down scroll I want to refresh the list with dynamic data from rest API. I am not able to identify user's scroll direction correctlly. Please help and if there is any betteer way other thank manually identifying scroll direction please share. Any helo would be appriciable.

Comment: You should use RecyclerView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code hope it will help you 
. you need to write below code in your main activity class

```
private int m_currentPage = 1;
private boolean m_isListLoading = false;
private int m_nLastIndex;

OnScrollListener m_onScroll = new OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView p_view, int p_scrollState)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView p_view, int p_firstVisibleItem, int p_visibleItemCount, int p_totalItemCount)
        {


            if (load(p_firstVisibleItem, p_visibleItemCount, p_totalItemCount))
            {

                if (m_currentPage < m_nTotalPages)
                {
                    m_isListLoading = true;
                    m_currentPage++;
                    // Call your api for next page index
                }
                // }
            }
        }
    };

protected boolean load(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        m_nLastIndex = firstVisibleItem;
        boolean lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && m_gvSalesGrid.getChildAt(visibleItemCount - 1) != null
                && m_gvSalesGrid.getChildAt(visibleItemCount - 1).getBottom() <= m_gvSalesGrid.getHeight();
        if (m_gvSalesGrid.getAdapter() == null)
            return false;
        return lastItem && !m_isListLoading;
    }
```

Make m_isListLoading = false after got api response

```
m_listview.setSelection(m_nLastIndex);
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but how to add data when user scrolls up as I would have cleaned the already loaded data. I tried this approach but using similar approach for up scrolling results in calling API two times one for upscroll and other for down scroll.

Comment: for that you need to reset your adapter and create new instance of Arraylist<yourVoObject> and store api response into it .

Comment: Ok  but how to seamlessly identify user has scrolled up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and implements a [RecyclerView.OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html) as shown on this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e)

Comment: recycler view I think do not suppport lower apis

Comment: It uses the support v7 library so it does support lower API